# Приведение типа

Tags: c++

В чем отличие этих двух способов приведения?

```
char c = 10;

int i = int(c);
float f = (float)c;
```

Comment: это - `(int) x; // old-style cast` и это: `int(x); // old-style cast` - одно и тоже, за исключение, что `int(x); - functional syntax`, а `(int) x; - old-style syntax`

Comment: Помимо отличия, у них есть сходство - ни то, ни другое в С++ использовать не следует.

Comment: Второе используется в шаблонном программирование неявно `template<class T> f() { SomeObject obj(T(120)); }` `T` может быть как и `int` так и любым типом имеющим конструктор от 120

Comment: @ffk может первое, а не второе?

Comment: Если что, то приведение типов в данном случае вообще не нужно. Обычно используется `(int), (float)` в выражениях, пр. `double a = (double) 10 / 6;`

Comment: @koshachok Это не очень хороший пример, такое приведение в C++ использовать не следует. Не стоит путать C и С++.

Comment: @VTT я думал, что парадигма приведения числовых типов такая же как в си; если же нет, то как?

Comment: @Abyx и похожий ответ :)

Comment: @koshachok В C++ используется [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) и static / reinterpret / const / dynamic cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба способа осуществляют явное преобразование типов.

Первый способ называется функциональной нотацией ([*functional notation*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv)), потому что выглядит так же как вызов функции. Он может использоваться только для простых спецификаторов типа, и не будет работать (компилироваться) на составных, например, для `unsigned char` или `long long int`. В случае составного типа можно использовать `typedef`:

```
typedef long double ld;
ld(42);          // ок 
long double(42); // ошибка
```

Если инициализатор не задан (т.е. в скобках пусто), то выражение `T()` даст *zero-initialized* значение указанного типа.

Второй способ представляет собой преобразование в сишном стиле ([*cast notation*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast)), т.к. использовался в языке C и для совместимости оставлен в C++. Такое преобразование, т.е. `(T)выражение`, интерпретируется компилятором вполне определённой последовательностью действий из явных преобразований (см. [ссылку](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)). Такое преобразование требует явного наличия преобразуемого выражения. Т.е. нельзя написать просто `(T)` и получить инициализированное нулём значение, как в предыдущем случае.